# Rx Buffer Winsock Socket programming C++. How to clear RX buffer?

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

I am receiving continuous video stream, I have to decode it and display it.
The camera is sending approx 20k packets(1288 byte) per second. I am getting stream up to like 10 seconds and the camera stops transmitting stream. I think this is due the buffer. I am trying to clear my buffer up by this code:

```
long a = 9965535;   
    if (setsockopt(camm, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (const char*)&a, sizeof(long)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting socket opts: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }


    do{

            Siz = recvfrom(camm, message, 1300, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &cam, &caml);

            image(message, Siz);
                aab++;
                if (aab > 1000){
            //  memset((char *)&ap, 0, 65535);// &ap, 65535
            //ap = "1288";
//                  memset(&a, 0, 9965535);
//                  *loc = 9965535;
//                  memset(loc, 0, 9965535);
                    aab = 0;
                    }
        } while (Siz > 0);
```

Can any one help me out of this issue?

Actually I don't want full frames to get decoded. I only need to decode the frame that is available. Means discarding remaining frames which are not able to come up for processing.

Comment: Your loop is incorrect. It should be `while ((Siz = recvfrom(...)) > 0)`. Otherwise you are processing data even at end of stream.

Comment: I did that, thanks for noticing this

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to actually read from the socket.  You might consider doing the reading in a dedicated thread, and have it store a video frame in a memory buffer only if the buffer is empty, discarding other frames in the meantime.  Another thread could then read and clear that memory buffer on its own timing as needed.

Comment: Program was working fine all the time, that was issue with the camera, the camera needs one bit high for continuous stream. Thanks for your help guys.